# Relative File Path For a Picture

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I have a problem with relative file paths. I wrote this line:

```
<img src="\bootstrap\Rezepte\GrilledFruitKebab.jpg">
```

It's not showing the picture, so I wanted to ask if anyone of you can help me.
The whole file path is:

```
C:\Users\if160109\Downloads\bootstrap-20171222T093142Z-001\bootstrap\Rezepte
```

The file path of my HTML file:

```
C:\Users\if160109\Downloads\bootstrap-20171222T093142Z-001\bootstrap\startbootstrap-blog-post-gh-pages\index.html
```

(I'm working on Windows)

Thank you for reading
(Sry if I'm doing any mistakes, but this is the first questions I ever asked here)

Comment: can you add more details? your file directory structure?

Comment: That’s not a relative path to begin with, so what should be the result? Where are the files?

Comment: Expecting you work on linux server, use `/` instead of `\\`.

Comment: Please, help us helping you, post the path to your image AND the path where the html is. Then the answer is going to be straightfroward. And do it by editing the question, not by adding more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, `<img src="../../Rezepte/GrilledFruitKebab.jpg">`

**Remember,**

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory **below**?
- Is the image in a directory **above**?

By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories. Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a look at my primitive example:
[image]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Answer (score 0):

Given your directory structure, the correct path would be

```
../Rezepte/GrilledFruitKebab.jpg
```

Because the `Rezepte` directory is a level above where your html lives.

Comment: Ok, what's wrong now? OP provided all the needed information.

Answer (score -3):

Try change the \ to / and remove the first /

Because this symbol in the first position will take the picture in your root folder. Or look the permission of the image.

You can see more about this here:

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

[Quick Reminder About File Path](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

> Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
>
> Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
>
> Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
>
> To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

or [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: @TarikTarikH try check the permission of the image, sometimes this can be the problem