# I am not able to use the background-image CSS as i have the photo in different folder in VS code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, background-image

I have saved the photo in a some other folder in VS code and my code is in some other folder and i want to use the photo as background image in code

```
background-image: url("\Photos\Desert.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

I tried this but the image is not showing;
If I put the image in the same folder as code and use  it is working

```
background-image: url("Desert.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a detailed explanation of how relative paths work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941081/22931682)

A small correction to your initial post will be to adjust the path since you are using *backward slash*

```
background-image: url("/Photos/Desert.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

Also, the reason it works when you put it in the same folder is because the relative path is at the root

```
background-image: url("Desert.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

Endeavor to place the image folder inside of the project.