# How to add a photo to the top right corner of the header?

Tags: html

[I have this website header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcxGt.png). Here´s the header´s code:

```
<body id="body"><a id="top"></a>
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <div class="wrap clearfix">
        <div id="logo" class="cover transition "><a href="/Ingbadino/index">Ing. Badino y Asoc. SRL </a></div> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="wrap clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="first"><a href="/" class="<?php if ($section=="home") print "active" ?>">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="empresa" class="<?php if ($section=="empresa") print "active" ?>">La Empresa</a></li>
                <li><a href="clientes" class="<?php if ($section=="clientes") print "active" ?>">Nuestros Clientes</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio" class="<?php if ($section=="portfolio") print "active" ?>">Portafolio de Obras</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="contacto" class="<?php if ($section=="contacto") print "active" ?>">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile_links"><a href="#" class="mobile_nav closed"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

And I want to add a photo to the top right corner of the header, what do I do?

I tried to add `<div <img src="images/img-clientes.gif" </div>` but it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you are targeting the relative path of the image to be able to display it. Find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941081/22931682)

Also, this is incorrect:

```
<div <img src="images/img-clientes.gif" </div>
```

here is the correct format:

```
<div> <img src="/images/img-clientes.gif" alt="logo"/> </div>
```

Endeavor to place the image folder inside of the project.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Yeah! You that's correct. It's often added for bare simplicity.