# How can I extend tailwind backgroundImages using image paths in React with vite?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm trying to extend tailwind backgroundImages and no matter what I put as the image's path it doesn't recognize. I tried search for the answer and wasn't able to figure out. I'm using vite in this project.

`tailwind.config.css`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'es': "url('/src/assets/images/es.png')",
        'us': "url('/src/assets/images/us.png')",
        'pt': "url('/src/assets/images/pt.png')",
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

I tried to use vite alias to configure in some way, as well as trying multiple image paths including change the folder to `public`. But neither did work.

Answer (score 0):

save your image in src/assets and in extends create a backgroundImage cofig in tailwind.config.js like this:

```html
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: { 'testBg': "url('/src/assets/test-image.jpg')" }
     },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

so you can use it like this :

```html
<div className="bg-testBg">
...
</div>
```

i attach some image for you.
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have your images in your public directory, it's best to access it as so:

`/assets/images`

Find more here on [how to handle image paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941081/22931682)

```
backgroundImage: {
    'es': "url('/assets/images/es.png')",
    'us': "url('/assets/images/us.png')",
    'pt': "url('/assets/images/pt.png')",
  }
```

then you can access the class as:

- bg-es
- bg-us
- bg-pt

```
<div className="bg-es"> 
   
</div>
```

```
<div className="bg-us"> 
   
</div>
```

```
<div className="bg-pt"> 
   
</div>
```